# Nested arrays in awk

Tags: awk

I have the following example file:

```
1 2  
2 4   
3 6   
4 8   
5 10  
6 12
```

I need to write some awk code that prints every line in the file followed by any line that has a difference of 8 or less in column $2,$2 is in increasing order.
the expected output should look like this:

```
1 2   
2 4   
3 6   
4 8
5 10  
2 4   
3 6   
4 8  
5 10  
6 12  
3 6   
4 8  
5 10  
6 12  
4 8  
5 10  
6 12
5 10  
6 12
```

I tried the below code

```
awk '{a[$1]=$0; for (i in a) print a[i]}' test.csv
```

Its giving me:

```
1 2  
1 2  
2 4  
1 2  
2 4  
3 6  
1 2  
2 4  
3 6  
4 8  
1 2  
2 4  
3 6  
4 8  
5 10  
1 2  
2 4  
3 6  
4 8  
5 10  
6 12
```

Comment: _8 or less_ or less than 8 (wrt `1 2` not followed by `5 10`)? ... but then again `2 4` is followed by `6 12`.

Comment: Also, please truncate that useless faulty output with values that aren't even in the sample data.

Comment: The output is fixed now, sorry for the mistake

Comment: To clarify, I need the script to check every line in the script, and compare it to the following lines, if the difference in $2 is 8 or less, the script will print that line followed by all the lines that fall within that condition. Line 1 (followed by all the lines with $2 <=8) Line2 (followed by all the lines with $2 <=8) and so on...

Comment: Is the input ordered? Does $1 always increase by 1, ie. $1==NR?

Comment: Yes, $2 is ordered (ascending) . but $1 is not increasing by 1

Comment: Please [edit] your question to contain the requirement you stated in your comments https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66742657/nested-arrays-in-awk#comment117984531_66742657 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66742657/nested-arrays-in-awk#comment117984837_66742657. Everything we need to know to help  you should be included in your question, not spread out across the question + comments, etc. where they're easy to miss.

Comment: Why the first block doesn't include `5 10` but the second block includes `6 12`?  In both cases the difference is 8.

Comment: @karakfa, yes you are write, I missed that in the example, I fixed it now, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a consistent implementation of the rule as I understand is

```
$ awk '{f[NR]=$1; s[NR]=$2}
    END{for(i=1;i<NR;i++)
          for(j=i;j<=NR;j++)
            if(s[j]-s[i]<6) print f[j],s[j]}' file
1 2
2 4
3 6
2 4
3 6
4 8
3 6
4 8
5 10
4 8
5 10
6 12
5 10
6 12
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear code, that answers my question.

Comment: trying to code the list in the comments but not able to, new to stackoverlflow

Comment: I need the first line to be 1 2, its skipped from the list.

Comment: thank you very much, that is exactly what I need, the last line should be if(s[j]-s[i]<=8) to be consistent with the question, the output list in my question was wrong and I updated now, sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution. The output is not exactly as the expected output but then again the expected output is inconsistent (regarding `1 2` vs `5 10` and `2 4` vs `6 12`, for example):

```
$ awk '{
    for(i in a) {             # for each record check all unprinted records
        if(($2-a[i])<8) {     # if less than 8 
            b[i]=b[i] ORS $0  # keep buffering records
        }
        else {                # until greater than or equal 
            print b[i]        # and then print and clean
            delete a[i]
            delete b[i]
        }
    }
    a[$1]=$2
    b[$1]=$0
}
END {                         # in the end 
    for(i in b)               # output all leftovers
        print b[i]
}' file
```

Since I'm using `for(i in a)` the order of buffers output might appear random.